# linux cp: how to have it follow links but not stop if a link target doesn't exist

Tags: linux, unix, cp

I want to recursively copy a dir and have the targets of the links copied, but I do not want the cp to stop if a target of a link does not exist.

For example, I run this command:

```
cp -fprL /path/to/src_dir /path/to_dest_dir
```

But the first time it hits symlink where the target doesn't exist it exits:

```
cp: cannot stat `/path/to/non-existent/file': No such file or directory
```

Is there some way to get cp to silently skip these and continue on?

Comment: When link is broken try [`-P`, `--no-dereference`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cp):  never follow symbolic links in SOURCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the standard GNU toolchain, no, there's no way.

You could instead copy your files, keeping symlinks as symlinks, then use `find -follow -type l -delete` to delete the broken symlinks, and then copy again, this time following symlinks.

Of course, you could also just write a python etc. program to do the copy for you, or find all files in the original trees that are not broken symlinks and use these with cp, replacing parts of the path with the target path using `sed`:

```
find -type d|sed 's/^\(.*\)/"\1" "\/target\/\1"/g'|xargs -p mkdir
find -follow -not -type l -not -type d|sed 's/^\(.*\)/"\1" "\/target\/\1"/g'|xargs -n2 cp
```

sed will duplicate your found file path, prefixing it with the target directory.

Comment: This is prone to potentially dangerous misbehavior if any filenames contain literal newlines. (Then again, following symlinks in general is unsafe if any directory inside the area covered is world-writable).

Comment: Very true, Charles Duffy. The same goes for `" `, by the way. You can work around that using `print0` for find, and `-0` for xargs, but things usually get ugly with 0 delimited strings in sed.

Comment: Indeed. One could work around that by doing the replacement in native bash rather than `sed`, given the inclination.

Comment: Oh, how would one go about doing that? My bash-foo is weak... I'd personally rather just abuse python for a while, but I'm eager to learn.

Comment: so, to iterate over an incoming NUL-delimited stream: `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do`. To replace would be `out=${in//$src/$dest}`, but if you're trying to replace only at the beginning of a string there are better approaches, all covered in the parameter expansion documentation. To generate another NUL-delimited stream on the output end, `printf '%s\0' "$out"` within the `while read` loop, if you aren't inclined to just invoke `cp` from within said loop directly.

Comment: BashFAQ #100 -- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100 -- is a good introduction to native string manipulation.

Comment: The "Complex Actions" subheading of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind may also be of interest, as an alternate way of communicating to the shell from `find` (passing located files on the argv of invoked shell processes, rather than via a NUL-delimited stream).